# Usage of "see" in English 1800s, stereotype or real?

Tags: american-english, nineteenth-century-english

When people are jokingly imitating how those in the 1800's USA are speaking they often use "see" at the end of a sentence instead of at the beginning like we might do so now.
An example would perhaps be
"See, now I'll take the apple."
vs
"Now I'll take the apple, see"

I'm wondering if this is historically accurate or just for comedic effect.

Comment: I suppose it's short for 'Do you see?' and is just a meaningless 'filler', in the same way that some modern speakers pepper their conversation with 'Know what I mean?' I don't think it's meant as a joke, just an imitation of the way some 19th century writers represented the speech of less educated people.

Comment: Actually, I think people still use "see" very frequently that way today.

Comment: I don't find either ordering particularly unusual.

Comment: @KateBunting might you have any specific writers or works in mind? Thanks for the comment too!

Comment: No, sorry, I don't - do you?

Comment: I recall it being commonly used in gangster movies from around 1930 to 1950. For instance, I'd associate it particularly with the characters played by James Cagney.

Comment: Not just USA. I read this in a stereotypical British police officer voice.